# Conditional format if the most recent of a range of cells matches my criteria

Tags: excel, excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to get a cell to conditionally format to shade in IF the most recently entered of a series of cells is <9.

The purpose of this is for a school seating plan, so if their most recent result is below a C their name's cell fills grey.

I've searched and tried different methods but am at a brick wall. Any ideas?

E.g - a string of numbers 11,8,9,5,6,7 relates to a grade, if the most recently entered is below 9 I'd like the name to fill grey.

Note: HLOOKUP to find the most right cell isn't possible because on the same row are multiple copies of the image below.

Answer (score 0):

Please try selecting ColumnA (assuming your values are entered there in time order descending) and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(ISBLANK(A2),A1<9,A1<>"")
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select grey formatting, OK, OK.